# Trigger.IO: Action handler on native back button?

Tags: trigger.io

Is it correct that native back buttons don't use their action handlers?

This works, it fires the alert message (regular native button):

```
forge.topbar.addButton( {text:"Button", position:"left"}, function(){ alert("OK") }, null);
```

But this doesn't work (native back button):

```
forge.topbar.addButton( {text:"Button", position:"left", type:"back"}, function(){ alert("OK") }, null );
```

...If so, how can I find out that the back button has been pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> **type:** Create a special type of button, the only option currently is
>   "back" which means the button will cause the webview to go back when
>   pressed.

I think the back button will basically trigger a ´window.history.back()´. It probably doesn't take a callback different from that.